# Timer alternative to measure request rate on the server side

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

I have client-server application in which i need to measure the rate of request arrival per second(Request rate). For this, i have a timer object that activates after every seconds, reads a synchronized counter and then sets it to zero. The counter increments on each request arrival.I used following code to detect request rate. There are so many other threads and timers in my application running.The problem is "due to the inaccuracy of timers i am not getting the perfect request rate". Is there any alternative of measuring request rate other than using timers.

```
public class FrequencyDetector extends TimerTask {
RequestCounter requestCounter;
FrequencyHolder frequencyHolder;

    public FrequencyDetector(RequestCounter requestCounter,FrequencyHolder frequencyHolder){
    this.frequencyHolder=new FrequencyHolder();
    this.frequencyHolder=frequencyHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
           int newFrequency=requestCounter.getCounter();
           frequencyHolder.setFrequency(newFrequency);
           requestCounter.setCounterToZero();
          //calls to other fuctions    
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking counter per unit time you can check time per unit counter. That will probably give you more accurate results. Algorithm is given below.

1. Increment counter on every request.
2. When counter reaches a certain `FIXED_LIMIT` calculate frequency by `frequency=FIXED_LIMIT/duration since last record`
3. Reset the counter and start with step 1

However this will record frequency at unpredictable intervals and if frequency of request decreases the duration between successive records will increase.

To handle it we can implement an adaptive algorithm, algorithm is given below.

1. Increment the counter on every request.
2. When counter reaches a certain `ADAPTIVE_LIMIT` record frequency as `frequency=ADAPTIVE_LIMIT/duration since last record`
3. Change ADAPTIVE_LIMIT as `ADAPTIVE_LIMIT=frequency * DESIRED RECORD INTERVAL`
4. Reset counter and start with step 1.

Above algorithm will reset the limit based on frequency last recorded. It's given that it will not be recording at optimal intervals but it will be pretty close.

Also it will give you highly accurate frequencies as it does not depend on any scheduled thread.

Following is an implementation of such an adaptive counter.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class TestCounter {
    //Keep initial counterInterval to a small value otherwise first record may take long time
    final AtomicLong counterInterval = new AtomicLong(10);
    AtomicLong requestCounter = new AtomicLong();
    volatile long lastTime;
    /**OPTIMAL_DURATION is the duration after which frequency is expected to be recorded
     * Program adaptively tries to reach this duration
     */
    static final double OPTIMAL_DURATION = 1.0; // 1 second
    static final Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started ");

        TestCounter main = new TestCounter();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            main.requestArrived();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Simulating requests
     */
    public void requestArrived() {
        printCounter();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //This will be in some Utility class
    private void printCounter() {
        requestCounter.incrementAndGet();
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentInterval = counterInterval.get();

        if(requestCounter.get() > currentInterval) {
            if(lastTime != 0) {
                long timeDelta = currentTime - lastTime;
                long frequency = (long)(currentInterval / (timeDelta / 1e9));
                System.out.printf("time=%.2f, frequency=%d\n", (timeDelta / 1e9), frequency);

                //updating the currentInterval for the miss
                long newCounterInterval = (long)(frequency * OPTIMAL_DURATION);
                counterInterval.set(newCounterInterval);
            }
            requestCounter.set(0);
            lastTime = currentTime;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Started 
time=0.54, frequency=18
time=0.98, frequency=18
time=1.01, frequency=17
time=0.96, frequency=17
time=0.99, frequency=17
time=0.85, frequency=19
time=0.96, frequency=19
time=0.82, frequency=23
time=1.08, frequency=21
time=0.98, frequency=21
time=0.94, frequency=22
time=1.06, frequency=20
time=1.07, frequency=18
time=0.99, frequency=18
time=0.98, frequency=18
time=1.02, frequency=17
time=0.92, frequency=18
time=0.92, frequency=19
time=0.89, frequency=21
time=0.82, frequency=25
time=1.31, frequency=19
time=1.02, frequency=18
```